# How to give items in MySQL table searchable "tags"

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a MySQL table in the following style:

Name                    Tags
technology           PC,computers,gaming
Computers            gaming, keyboard, monitor

etc.

I want to know if it is possible to make these searchable. for example if someone searches "PC" then technology will be the result. If someone searches "gaming" then technology and computers will be the results. So far my code is as follows:

```
<?php
//Include the connection file
include "subconnect.php";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM subs";



if(isset($_POST['search'])) {

     $search_term = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search_box']);


     $sql .= " WHERE tags = '{$search_term}'";

}


$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

?>

<form name="search_form" method="POST" action="subsearch.php">

   Search: <input type="text" name="search_box" value="" />

   <input type="submit" name="search" value="Enter a category to find Subreddits!">
</form>
<table width="70%" cellpadding="5" cellspace="5">

<tr>
<td><h1>Name</h1></td>

</tr>
<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>

</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can perform a [string comparisons](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html) o a [regex match](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html), but I don't think that is the best way

The best way is to create a support table "Tags" and create a relationship n -> n with the original table.

Answer (score 0):

Lightly tested

So, am I to understand that you have a database setup with columns, and among them is a sort of tags column?

Well if so then yes, you can indeed search for them with the RLIKE command (among many others I'm sure)

```
SELECT * FROM subs WHERE tags RLIKE 'PC'
```

That should do it. Remember to escape data being inputted. Perhaps making a sort of request_var function like in PhpBB would help you out a little?